# Getting referrence error while creating new array of object from existing array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of image urls and I am trying to create a new object which should look like this:
`source: { uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/XP2BE7q.jpg' }`

So I have used reduce() to do that. Now I want that modified imageArray and assign it state variable called images (which must be an array) but I am getting reference error imageArray not defined why so?

I want to assign newly created imageArray to the state variable, how can I do that? Currently, I am getting reference Error should I move `reduce()` operation outside the class component.

Code:

```
export default class ImageView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      images: imageArray
    };
  }
  render() {
    const imageArray = this.props.images.reduce((acc, images) => {
      let temp = {
        source: {
          uri: images
        }
      };

      acc.push(temp);
      return acc;
    }, []);
    console.log(imageArray);
    return <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: In the constructor you reference imageArray which is not defined yet. Instead initialize the images in the state with an empty array and in componentDitMount create the imageArray and setState with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
export default class ImageView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      images: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const imageArray = this.props.images.reduce((acc, images) => {
      let temp = {
        source: {
          uri: images
        }
      };

      acc.push(temp);
      return acc;
    }, []);

    this.setState({ images: imageArray });
  }
  render() {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nguyen If I move the code outside class component I am getting undefined `images` on which I am mapping why so ? see this -> https://imgur.com/a/bSx0muV

Comment: Nope! `Outside class component` won't work for sure :)

Comment: @Nguyen Why what is the reason ?

Comment: Because we're trying to get the value of the `images` property from the `props` object :) the `props` object is only accessible inside the instance of a class component.

Comment: @Nguyen Sorry your code is working fine you previously you used `componentDidMounted` instead of `componentDidMount` :)

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `imageArray` inside your render method, which is outside the scope of your `constructor`.  I suggest calling `this.setState({ images: imageArray });` after you define image array, which should NOT be happening inside the `render` method.  Initialize state.images as an empty array.  In `componentDidMount`, reduce your `this.props.images` and then call `setState`.

Comment: @Iarz Should I remove `reduce()` outside class component ? but then will this.props.images will work ?

Comment: You have access to your props anywhere.  I'm going to amend my initial response and suggest that you set images to an empty array in your constructor, and then in `componentDidMount`, do your `this.props.images.reduce` magic and use `setState` to update the state.

Comment: If I move the code outside class component I am getting undefined `images` on which I am mapping why so ? see this -> https://imgur.com/a/bSx0muV